# Coverage probability estimation for Bayesian Credible interval (Normal Distribution)

Tags: r, bayesian, normal-distribution, credible-interval

Bayesian Inference for the Normal Distribution, I use the following `r` code to obtain the posterior distribution.

```
install.packages(c("mvtnorm","loo","coda"), repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/",dependencies=TRUE)
options(repos=c(getOption('repos'), rethinking='http://xcelab.net/R'))
install.packages('rethinking',type='source')
library(rethinking)

set.seed(650)
x <- data.frame(x = rt(100,3))

fit <- rethinking::map(
  alist(
    x ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
    mu ~ dnorm(1, 10),
    sigma ~ dunif(0, 50)
  ),
  data=x)

precis(fit, corr=TRUE)

sim_post <- extract.samples(fit)
dim(sim_post)
post_mean <- apply(sim_post, 2, mean)
post_mean

quantile(sim_post$mu ,  c(.05, .95))
quantile(sim_post$sigma, c(0.05, 0.95))
```

I have simulated 10000 samples using the posterior distribution. How can I obtain the coverage probability for mu?

Comment: I don't see a package named "rethinking" in CRAN. You should tell us where you got it and how to install it.

Comment: `install.packages(c("mvtnorm","loo","coda"), repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/",dependencies=TRUE)
options(repos=c(getOption('repos'), rethinking='http://xcelab.net/R'))
install.packages('rethinking',type='source')` , Here is the link, https://xcelab.net/rm/software/

Comment: [This related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284179/coverage-probability-of-credible-intervals-if-we-take-bayesian-model-literally) might be of interest. Seems like the approach is the standard empirical one: repeatedly generate random samples from the prior, then count how often the posterior interval encompasses the true parameter values.

Comment: Are there any `r` function can be used for this purpose?

Comment: @score324, not that I am aware. It's not something typically computed/reported - though that doesn't mean it shouldn't be.

Comment: Coverage probability is a concept related to a frequentist interpretation of probability. In Bayes' analysis the posterior tells you everything. A x% posterior interval will contain, by definition, x% of the times the true value (provided that your model is correct).

Comment: @nicola, why I am getting 100% always?

Comment: Are you getting 100% from what? If you want to make Bayesian analysis just forget about coverage probability. It's a concept that has its scope within frequentism.

Comment: @nicola Thank you.